# How to create a scrollable well panel without being constrained by the Shiny grid layout system?

Tags: r, shiny, scroll

In the example code posted at the bottom, I use a `wellPanel()` for six user inputs. I'm trying to expand the user inputs to the right in the `wellPanel()` as shown in the image immediately below, using a slide control for the user to move to the right in that `wellPanel()` in order to reveal the additional input widgets. I currently use the standard Shiny grid layout, where the max of all column widths is limited to 12 which is the only way I know how to neatly arrange input widgets in rows/columns. Is there a way to add additional columns to the right in that `wellPanel()` while maintaining the current input widget widths, with the user scrolling to the right for viewing those additional inputs? I'm not wedded to the grid layout system, if there's another way to neatly arrange Shiny input widgets in rows/columns. The current layout for the six input widgets is neat, although limiting.

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  wellPanel(id = "tPanel",style = "overflow-x:scroll",
    fluidRow(
      column(5,
          selectInput("viewType","View options:",c("plot")),
          numericInput("winStart","Start month of study:",value = 0, max = 15, min = 0),
          selectInput("uniCov", "Single-predictor for KM:",c("None" = 1))
      ),
      column(5,
          selectInput("curveType","View survival plot:",c("Survival" = "pct")),
          numericInput("winEnd","End month of study:", value = 40, max = 40, min = 20),
          selectizeInput("multiCov", "Multi-predictors for Cox:",c("Node" = "Node"))
      )
    )
  ),
  h4("Plots go here...")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way with `splitLayout`:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(), br(),
  wellPanel(
    style = "overflow-x: scroll",
    splitLayout(
      # first column
      column(
        12,
        numericInput("i1", "I1", 1)
      ),
      # second column
      column(
        12,
        numericInput("i2", "I2", 2)
      ),
      # third column
      column(
        12,
        numericInput("i3", "I3", 3)
      ),
      # column widths
      cellWidths = "40%"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I just learned something new. Looks very nice in the complete code this is intended for.